# Cross-origin: refresh parent window when child window is closed

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to refresh the parent window when the child window is closed by the user.

```
var newWindow = MakeNewWindow("https://samedomainurl.com");
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if(newWindow.closed) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
}, 2000);
```

This code works on Internet Explorer version 11.0.47

But in Internet Explorer 11.0.29 `newWindow.closed` becomes `true` even when the `newWindow.location.href` changes to "https://differentdomainurl.com" (this happens when the user clicks any link on https://samedomainurl.com).

Due to this, the parent window refreshes before the window is actually closed.
Also, I have no control over "https://differentdomainurl.com".

I want a solution that works for Internet Explorer specifically.

Comment: well once the window url is changed, it is a little hard to detect it because of same origin policy.

Comment: I can see that you are only setting the URL while making a new window. So it will not able to find the window after URL get changed. I suggest you to set a name parameter for your window. So you can identify the window using it's name even if the URL get changed. Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp